# How to chain multiple LESSOPEN scripts?

Tags: less, syntax-highlighting

Linux distributions nowadays have a default `LESSOPEN` set to `/usr/bin/lesspipe` which allows one to easily inspect e.g. zipped files or PDF files.

Now I wanted to see whether I can add syntax highlighting to less. This is easily accomplished with [source-highlight](https://superuser.com/q/71588/76688). I used `LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/source-highlight -i %s -q -f esc"` and it works fine.

But now the problem becomes: How do I get the behavior of both lesspipe and source-highlight? Simply appending one after the other doesn't work:

```
$ export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s | /usr/bin/source-highlight -i %s -q -f esc"
$ less foo
Invalid LESSOPEN variable
```

It also doesn't make sense so this is not really surprising.

Is it possible to set this up without writing elaborate scripts? The best case would be to have chaining, i.e., provide syntax highlight for a zipped file as well.

Comment: What are actual `pipe1` and `pipe2` you used?

Comment: @cuonglm I added the commands.

Comment: Try `export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s | /usr/bin/source-highlight -q -f esc"`, this will prevent the error, but I think won't work as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The command in the `LESSOPEN` variable after the initial pipe is executed by the shell indicated by the `SHELL` environment variable and must produce the desired content on its standard output.

You can pass the output of `lesspipe` as input to another command that reads from standard input and writes to standard output. However, in order for `source-highlight` to read from its standard input, it needs to be told what language to highlight for, so `source-highlight` doesn't work this way.

When `lesspipe` doesn't recognized a file format, it prints nothing, which less interprets as an indication to read the original file. If you have [`ifne`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) from [Joey Hess's moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), you can use it to detect this case and try `source-highlight` instead. You'll need to save the original file name in a variable so that you can use it twice.

```
LESSOPEN='|file=%s; /usr/bin/lesspipe "$file" | /usr/bin/ifne -n /usr/bin/source-highlight -i "$file" -o STDOUT 2>/dev/null'
```

Note that you'll need to include `-r` or `-R` in `$LESS` or type `-r` or `-R` after starting `less` in order for less to render the colors.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about lessutils yet, they look nice. We're 90% there. Syntax highlight does not yet work for files that went through lesspipe but I'm sure I can make it work somehow.